# Jupyter notepad cannot find PyPDF2

Tags: windows, pip, jupyter, pypdf

I am new to Python 3.10.5  under Windows 10 64-bit.   I have tried installing pip and pip3 and using them to install PyPDF2 but a Windows File Explorer scan of my C: drive finds no file names that include "PyPDF2".   My project is at a standstill until I find a way of getting Jupyter notepad to import PyPDF2.   HELP!

Comment: That is not a PyPDF2 issue, but a general "how do I install packages on windows / in juypter" issue

Comment: ". I have tried installing pip and pip3 and using them to install PyPDF2" what exactly did you try? Which error messages did you see?

Comment: I believe this was cross-posted and a solution offered [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/cannot-get-to-command-prompt-mode-in-jupyter-notebook/14818/2?u=fomightez).